# The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent

Tags: python, numerical-integration

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
from mpmath import coth

DvDc = 6.5
dens = 5.65
Vs = 4.6e3
a = 3.3e-9
w0 = np.sqrt(2)*Vs/a
T = 50 
kb = 1.38064852e-5  # in eV`
j0 = (DvDc)**2 / ((2*np.pi)**2 *dens*Vs**5)

def func(x):
    return x*np.exp(-(x/w0)**2)*coth(x/(2*kb*T))
S = j0*integrate.quad(func, 0, np.inf)[0]
print(S)
```

Hi, so I have no experience using numerical integration, but I was wondering if anybody can help.
Here I have some variables defined, and have a function that I want to integrate. However I get back "The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent." And pretty much get the same result despite what I put in the denominator of coth.

Does anybody know if I'm making a mistake or perhaps I just can't do this integral.

Thanks!

Comment: what is integrate.quad?

Comment: Coth is undefined at zero which will probably cause a problem for numerical integration

Comment: Hi, integrate.quad is from the scipy package

Comment: Do you know what the right answer is? I get 4.598332106511304e-20

Comment: f you look at the graph of cot() , you will see it is a periodic function, going from positive infinity to negative infinity indefinitely. No matter how large the value of  gets, it will keep repeating this way and never tends to any one value of . Hence, the problem here is the infinity not the 0.

Comment: @DarkDrassher34 This is coth, not cot ...

Comment: I don't know the actual answer, but I get that value whether or not I include the coth term, which doesn't seem right to me

Comment: @fissioni Are you sure about the values, especially `w0`? You have `2*kb*T`, which is 1e-3, but w0, which is almost 2e12. So the two factors change on scales 15 orders of magnitude apart. I don't know the background of your problem, but this bothers me somewhat.

Comment: @mcsoini The values I'm getting are from a PhD thesis I'm referring to for my undergrad project, it lists those values I have in the code, Vs has a power of 10^3 in metres per second, and a is 3.3 nanometres. I wrote the variable as x but it's actually the frequency w. Also, I used my own version which  'should' be the same as the thesis, and instead of coth I have `(2/(np.exp(x/(kb*T))-1) +1)`, but it gives the same result.

Comment: I do think you have an issue with your values. Note that for smaller values of `w0` the numerical integration works just fine. Especially, why is `kb = 1.38064852e-5  # in eV`? Assuming that you mean Boltzmann, it's either 1.38×10−23 **J/K**, or `8.62×10−5` ***eV/K**, but not a mix of the two.

Comment: @mcsoini I think you're right, if I write the velocity Vs in terms of metres per picosecond, and then my frequency w0 is scaled down massively, then the integration doesn't give an error. I'm also not sure how I managed to get that Boltzmann value... I think I just changed the power but forgot the 1.6 factor from the electron charge. Thanks a lot for yout help!

Answer (score 7):

There a some difficulties with your integrand. First, although the function is not divergent, it may look like it for the integration scheme. Just plot it:

[image]

That's because your `w0` is `1971327996035.2234`, so the `exp(-x**2)` suppression only happens *very* far to the right. Use variable substitution `y = x / w0` to get it right. Second, the function is not defined at `x=0` (because you divide by tanh) but can be continuously extended with `2 * kb * T`.

```py
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DvDc = 6.5
dens = 5.65
Vs = 4.6e3
a = 3.3e-9
w0 = np.sqrt(2) * Vs / a
T = 50
kb = 1.38064852e-5  # in eV`
j0 = (DvDc) ** 2 / ((2 * np.pi) ** 2 * dens * Vs ** 5)


def func(x):
    return x * np.exp(-((x / w0) ** 2)) / np.tanh(x / (2 * kb * T))


def func2(y):
    return np.where(
        y > 0,
        y * w0 * np.exp(-(y ** 2)) / np.tanh(y * w0 / (2 * kb * T)),
        2 * kb * T
    )

val, err = integrate.quad(func2, 0, np.inf)
val *= w0  # y = x / w0  =>  dx = dy * w0
print(val)
```

```
1.943067033976125e+24
```

A plot of  `func2`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
For positive <math>w</math> and <math>t</math>
<math>
\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2/w^2}\coth(x/t) dx
=
t^2
\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2(t/w)^2}\coth(x) dx</math>

<math>
=
t^2 
\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2(t/w)^2}\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1} dx


=
t^2
\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2(t/w)^2}\frac{1+e^{-2x}}{1-e^{-2x}} dx

=
t^2 
\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2(t/w)^2}[1+2e^{-2x}+2e^{-4x}+2e^{-6x}+\cdots] dx
.
</math>
As a shortcut $t\approx 0.00138064$, $w\approx 0.19713\times 10^{13}$, $\alpha\equiv w/t\approx 0.14278\times 10^{16}$.
All these integrals can be written in terms of the complementary error function:
<math>

=t^2
\big[
\frac{\alpha^2}{2}
+\sqrt\pi \alpha e^{\alpha^2} \mathrm{erfc} (\alpha)
+\sqrt\pi \alpha e^{4\alpha^2} \mathrm{erfc}(2 \alpha)
+\sqrt\pi \alpha e^{9\alpha^2} \mathrm{erfc}(3 \alpha)+\cdots
\big]
</math>
Because <math>\alpha</math> is large, one can use the factorial series representations
<math>
j \sqrt\pi \alpha e^{j^2\alpha^2} \mathrm{erfc}(j\alpha)\approx   1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(j^2\alpha^2+1)}
+\frac14\frac{1}{(j^2\alpha^2+1)(j^2\alpha^2+2)}



\approx
t^2
\big[
\frac{\alpha^2}{2}
+1-\frac12\frac{1}{\alpha^2+1}
+\frac12-\frac14\frac{1}{4\alpha^2+1}
\big]

So the result is basically <math>(t\alpha)^2/2=w^2/2 \approx 1.94307\times 10^{24}</math>.
```